# A term for making an object behave like an animal

Tags: verbs, nouns, vocabulary

I'm writing a fanfiction and I can't seem to find the word for making an inanimate object act like an animal.

I'm writing from the object's point of view, it supposed to act like a fledgling bird. (ie; is capable of loyalty to humans, can actually get hungry and expect to be fed, associate action with reward, can be trained.)

Comment: its the opposite of anthromorphism

Comment: theriomorphize? But to anthropomorphize something is to look at it as being human, not to make it act like a human. So it's not a perfect analogy.

Comment: How about "animate"? ;)

Answer (score 1):

It falls under ***zoomorphism***.

> Zoomorphism is a derivative of a Greek word *zōon* that means animal and *morphē* means form or shape. It is a literary technique in which **the animal attributes are imposed upon non-animal objects**, humans, and events and animal features are ascribed to humans, gods and other objects.
>
> [*literarydevices.net*](http://literarydevices.net/zoomorphism/)